# фильтрация и сортировка картинок по папкам Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, консоль

Есть ли возможность отсортировать фото по папкам исходя из первых символов изображения? 
Скачать через wget кучу изображений в одну папку, у фото есть наименование взятое из артикля. Например 0123.jpg   0123-A1.jpg 0123-A2.jpg  нужно создать папку 0123 и закинуть туда эти изображения. так же есть 234567.jpg 23456-A1.jpg 23456-A2.jpg для нее так же создать дерикторию 23456 и закинуть эти фото. Искал пакетный фильтр, но что-то не как. 
Изображений около 4х тысяч, не хочется в ручную...

Comment: На будущее, смотрите в строну renrot.

Comment: возможно  я плохо гуглю по теме renrot. Вы могли бы подробно описать что это и с чем его едят?

Comment: *apt install renrot; man renrot*. В Ubuntu, если мне не изменяет память, был. Позволяет переименовывать по шаблону и сортировать файлы с картинками, можно и ещё другие типы файлов туда же.

Answer (score 1):

Товарищ помог

```
#!/bin/bash
for z in `ls | grep jpg | grep -v -`;do name=`echo $z| cut -d . -f1` ; echo $name ; mkdir -p $name; mv $name* $name/;done
```